# Listing all the version of a secret residing in Azure Key Vault in Jenkins active choice parameter list

Tags: azure, jenkins, groovy, azure-keyvault

As part of work of a Jenkins pipeline, I would like to be able to choose from a secret from a drop down list, and then from another list choose which version of that secret to use. I started by creating the first list using the active choice parameter in Jenkins and adding the different names *manually*, as in

> groovy script : return ["secret1","secret2","secret3"]

so the second list or the second active choice reactive is something along this scenario: depending on the secret selected, it will query the akv and fetch back its versions.

Is this doable? and if so does anyone have an idea how to implement it because I have tried to query the AKV with Service Principle credentials saved within Jenkins but no luck.